# How to find failure sql statement when executing as a batch

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am running sql insertion as a batch

```
statement.executeBatch();
```

When one of the multiple rows fails it throws the BatchUpdateExeception.

I want to know which row it has failed.

Example:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (V500.XFK1Employee) violated - parent key not found
```

In this case EmployeeID is not found in its parent table,

I am inserting 3 rows .. one of them failed due to foreign key constraint, can I find out which EmployeeID it failed to insert into SQL using BatchUpdateException ?

This is just a small example I have 100's of rows that are executing as a batch

Answer (score 0):

Hope the link helps you resolve the issue - https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-find-which-statement-failed-in-a-jdbc-batch-update/.

1. A good way to log JDBC statements, and [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) is [one of the best ways of logging JDBC PreparedStatement(s)](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/)
2. We also need to catch the `BatchUpdateException` and find the number of statements that were sucessfully executed by calling the `getUpdateCounts` method